# What is the relation between Kullback loss and L1 and L2 loss?

Tags: references, distance-functions

I tried to find some relation between these distance (loss) measures, but couldn't find any references. However, I think it must something like this: 
$$
\sqrt 2*D_{KL} < L_1 < L_2
$$
Is that right?

Comment: Please explain what you might mean by "$\lt$" when comparing loss *functions.*

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify, so I'm going to assume the following definitions:

$$
L_1(p_1,p_2) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}|p_1(x)-p_2(x)|
$$

$$
L_2(p_1,p_2) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}|p_1(x)-p_2(x)|^2
$$

$$
D_{KL}(p_1,p_2) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p_1(x)\log (p_1(x)/p_2(x) )
$$

where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are distributions over the random variable $X$ in the space $\mathcal{X}$.

In that case,

> $D_{KL}(p_1,p_2) \geq \frac{1}{2 \ln(2)}L_1(p_1,p_2)^2$ for all $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$

This is proved in Elements of Information Theory by Cover & Thomas, chapter 11. The proof is a bit long for me to copy verbatim, and I don't know any online references. Sorry.

By inspection, I also think it's safe to say

> $L_2(p_1,p_2) \leq L_1(p_1,p_2)$ for all $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$

This is because for any $x$, we have $|p_1(x)-p_2(x)|\leq 1$. Hence, 
$$
|p_1(x)-p_2(x)|^2 \leq |p_1(x)-p_2(x)|
$$
and so
$$
\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} |p_1(x)-p_2(x)|^2 \leq \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}}|p_1(x)-p_2(x)|
$$
which seems to prove it.

So it looks like your original ordering of the inequalities is roughly backwards!